# CGContext color changes when alpha is really small

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I'm making a painting app and at each point along a stroke the width of the brush can change size and the alpha decreases as if the brush was running out of paint. The problem is that when the alpha gets really small the color changes.

Once the alpha goes below .01 I start to get the color changes in the brush strokes. I have to have such a low alpha because at every pixel along the line I am overlaying the brush layer into the context and to get the needed transparency as the brush is running out of paint, the alpha ends up needing to be very small.

Here is the code where I am drawing my layer into the context:

```
    CGContextSaveGState(_cacheContext);
    CGContextSetAlpha(_cacheContext, _brushAlpha); // below .01 color starts to change
    CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint (_cacheContext, bottomLeft, _brushShapeLayer);
    CGContextRestoreGState(_cacheContext);
```

[image: First color is correct the others are incorrect as the alpha gets lower]

If the RGB color is all one color such as (1,0,0) then it works great. But when the color is something else like (.4,.6,.2) thats when I see the color changes at low alphas.

Thanks for any help!

*** Update ***

I tried to use kCGBitmapFloatComponents but I am getting an error:

> Unsupported pixel description - 3 components, 32 bits-per-component,
>   128 bits-per-pixel

I assumed this meant that I couldn't use it in iOS but maybe I'm not setting it up correctly. Here is what I have for creating the context:

```
bitmapBytesPerRow = (self.frame.size.width * 8 * sizeof(float));
bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * self.frame.size.height);

void* bitmap = malloc( bitmapByteCount );

CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapFloatComponents;
self.cacheContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmap, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height, 32, bitmapBytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo);
```

My Deployment Target is set at 8.2

Comment: Check your math on the bytesPerRow and bitsPerComponent fields.  Your numbers aren't consistent. You have 32 bits per component and 3 or 4 components, yielding 12 or 16 bytes per pixel. But in your bytesPerRow calculation, you are using 32 bytes per pixel (8 * 4)

Comment: I tried both 
bitmapBytesPerRow = (self.frame.size.width * 12); 
and 
bitmapBytesPerRow = (self.frame.size.width * 16); 

both gave me the same error...Thanks for the ideas though!

Comment: I deleted my old answer because I tried to replicate what you're seeing with a bitmap context (using one byte per component) and I'm not seeing the same issue.  I think there might be an issue in part of the code that you have not posted.

I put together a little sample app for you. here:

https://github.com/aegolden/BitmapContextFingerpaint

that (I think) does what you're describing, but I see no color change as the alpha becomes very small.

Comment: @AaronGolden Thanks for setting that up! In that sample app you created if you increase the line width to something like 60 instead of 10 and then multiply the alpha by .95 instead of .9 - the effect becomes more pronounced. It will turn different shades/colors, and go black at the end. The rgb I specified was just an example. Try 0.8,0.7,0.9 and you can really see the colors change.

Comment: @Kevin I tried those settings but still didn't see the color change, maybe some *very* subtle changes, but certainly nothing as dramatic as in your screenshot, and nothing turned black…  Maybe you can fork my project and set up some sample parameters to demonstrate the issue.  I also wonder which device types, OS versions, and simulators you've tried, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: @AaronGolden Here is the forked project: https://github.com/kevray/BitmapContextFingerpaint The alpha needs to be really low so it shows transparency. The longer you draw the line the more color changes you will see. Also, the sample app strokes a path at every touchesMoved which redraws the whole path every time, layering it on top of the previously drawn path so the changes in color will be more subtle than the way I am drawing which is interpolating points along a line and drawing a circle at every point. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronGolden I have been testing on an iPad Air 2 and just tried it on an iPhone 6. It was actually a little less noticeable on the iPhone 6 but definitely still happened...